# Can isAlive() be False immediately after calling start() because the thread hasn't yet started?

Tags: python, multithreading, race-condition

In the python documentation at http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects it says that

> [isAlive()] returns True just before the run() method starts until just after the run() method terminates

But then the start() method says that:

> [start()] arranges for the object’s run() method to be invoked in a separate thread of control.

Does this mean if I call `t.start()` and then immediately check `t.isAlive()` it's possible I could get `False` because the thread hasn't started yet?

Comment: I doubt it, unless the thread terminates very very quickly.

Comment: @Will: it cannot have terminated very quickly if it hasn't started yet. I don't think this question is interested in the answer to the separate question, "can it return False because the thread has terminated?", despite the title :-)

Comment: I'll clarify the title

Comment: @SteveJessop, he asks at the end if he calls isAlive() immediately if it could return False. It certainly could but admittedly not because it didn't start. This is a very valid thread timing issue.

Comment: @Will In my case (and I think in many cases) I don't mind if isAlive() returns False because it's finished already.  I just want to make sure successive calls to isAlive() can't be False and then True and from the documentation it's not clear that that can't happen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can't happen, at least not in CPython's implementation.  That comes from staring at the code for `Thread.start` (here from the Python 3 source, but it doesn't matter):

```
def start(self):
    ...
    try:
        _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
    except Exception:
        with _active_limbo_lock:
            del _limbo[self]
        raise
    self._started.wait()
```

`_start_new_thread()` is implemented in C, starting a new thread and running `self._bootstrap()` inside that new thread.  `self._bootstrap()` in turn invokes `self.run()`.  If that's all there were to it, then the invoking thread could indeed return an arbitrary amount of time before `run()` started to execute.  But the:

```
    self._started.wait()
```

at the end blocks on an internal `Event`.  The bootstrap code sets the `_started` `Event` shortly before invoking `run()`, and the state of that same event is the primary thing `isAlive()` looks at.

Comment: So then shouldn't the documentation say "This method returns True from when start() is called until just after the run() method terminates"?

Comment: What the docs say is accurate, but isn't enough to answer your question.  The change you suggest would answer your question, but isn't accurate (e.g., thread A creates a thread T and calls T.start(), T.start() just gets going, A loses its timeslice, thread B calls T.isAlive() and can certainly get False back).  It's tricky ;-)